# How to detect rxjs related memory leaks in Angular apps

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

Is there any tool or technique to detect "left behind" or "currently alive" observables, subscriptions.

Just recently discovered a pretty nasty memory leak where components were kept alive due to missing "unsubscribe" calls. I read about "takeUntil" approach which seems pretty good.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/2050306

However I'm still wondering is there any tool (browser extension etc.) for that. Augury does not cover this area as far as I know.

All input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a pretty good question. I guess the approach would be to treat it like an e2e test scenario and stub `subscribe()` with pass-through, then within the stub to monitor subscriptions. There's a flag on the observable which indicates 'closed', which would cover subscriptions that complete and therefore do not need an explicit unsubscribe.

Comment: @ischenkodv your edit is faulty - [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io) is the tool robert is referring to. Please revert.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker Yes, Augury the extension. That e2e test scenario is interesting do you have any working code for that?

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker sorry, reverted.

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/acutmore/leaks/blob/master/leaks.js

Comment: @jo_va looks promising unfortunately no luck making it work with Angular 7.

Comment: RxJava subscription leaks are particularly insidious in Android applications as well. If all else fails you could take inspiration from this library I wrote to debug Rx leaks on Android: https://github.com/mykwillis/RxLeakCheck

Comment: @MykWillis Thank you for your input I looked into RxLeakCheck.java

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the tool I mention below.

This can be accomplished by keeping a list where new subscriptions are added to, and removing subscriptions from this list once it is unsubscribed.

The troublesome part is *observing* subscriptions. A straightforward way to achieve this is by monkey-patching the `Observable#subscribe()` method, that is, replacing the Observable prototype method.

This is the overall approach of [observable-profiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/observable-profiler), a development tool which hooks into an Observable library (i.e rxjs) and prints leaking subscriptions in console.

A simple way to use the profiler is start tracking once the app is bootstraped, then stop tracking after a time:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { setup, track, printSubscribers } from 'observable-profiler';

setup(Observable);
platformBrowserDynamic([])
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(ref => {
        track();
        window.stopProfiler = () => {
            ref.destroy();
            const subscribers = track(false);
            printSubscribers({
                subscribers,
            });
        }
    });
```

Just call `stopProfiler()` in devtools console once you want a report.

Comment: Thank you. This looks really promising. Will come back with my findings shortly.

Comment: @robert feedback is appreciated!

Comment: @AndréWerlang does your tool work correctly with using pipe with takeUntil(...) for unsubscribing?  I used your tool and I got many errors from Angular Material components.

Comment: @AndréWerlang and it doesn't work correctly with streams closed with pipe(take(1) / first()), they are considered as not closed by your tool

Comment: @Tomasz these operators you mention unsubscribe from the stream once the underlying stream emits, and the tool only reports as error when they don't. I have found leaks on a third-party component and in angular itself, so that could be the case. Provide a repo/repro and I'll take a look.

Comment: This tool does not work for me in angular 7/8: i get errors at index.js:202
 Error
    at new SubscriptionSource (index.js:79)
    at EventEmitter.subscribe (index.js:112)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.subscribe (core.js:22123)
    at TooltipDirective.push../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tooltip/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-tooltip.js.TooltipDirective.ngOnInit (ngx-bootstrap-tooltip.js:332)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:19341)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:27597)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:27559)
...

Comment: @Spikolynn please use GitHub's issue tracker to report issues. Also, add a repro.